# How to get inputs value using a G_CALLBACK using GTK in C

Tags: c, parameters, callback, gtk, gtk3

I'm setting up a login window for something I need in a school project using GTK, CodeBlocks and Glade. It's just a simple form, username, password and a connect button. The problem is I can't get the value of the inputs because I can't send my builder to another function using the callbacks. I try to explain it as simple as I can, sorry for my bad English.

```
void verifyConnect(GtkButton *button, gpointer *builder){
    GtkWidget *passwordInput;
    GtkWidget *usernameInput;

    passwordInput = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(*builder, "passwordInput"));
    usernameInput = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(*builder, "usernameInput"));

    const gchar *text1 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(passwordInput));
    const gchar *text2 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(usernameInput));

    g_print("Username : %s\n",text2);
    g_print("Password : %s\n",text1);
}


void connectUser(){
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *connectButton;

    GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "loginWindow.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "loginWindow"));

    connectButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "connectButton"));
    g_signal_connect (connectButton, "clicked",G_CALLBACK(verifyConnect),&gtkBuilder);

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));

    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}
```

For now I'm getting this error when clicking on the connect button. 
I know what this error is, I just don't know how I can get my builder in the verifyConnect function:

```
(projet_c_gtk.exe:9928): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_builder_get_object: assertion `GTK_IS_BUILDER (builder)' failed

(projet_c_gtk.exe:9928): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_builder_get_object: assertion `GTK_IS_BUILDER (builder)' failed

(projet_c_gtk.exe:9928): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion `GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed

(projet_c_gtk.exe:9928): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion `GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed
Username : (null)
Password : (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is here:

```c
g_signal_connect (connectButton, "clicked",G_CALLBACK(verifyConnect),&gtkBuilder);
```

The `gtkBuilder` variable is already a pointer, so passing its address to `g_signal_connect()` eventually makes the corresponding callback argument a pointer *to a pointer*. That would be all nice and dandy, except for one little detail: the memory address you passed points to an automatic variable. Automatic vars are stored on the stack, and are deallocated when the function that uses them returns. After that, other functions may allocate the same space for their needs and rewrite the hell out of it.

This is what you need to do to resolve that:

```c
void verifyConnect(GtkButton *button, GtkBuilder *builder){
    GtkWidget *passwordInput;
    GtkWidget *usernameInput;

    passwordInput = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "passwordInput"));
    usernameInput = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "usernameInput"));

    const gchar *text1 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(passwordInput));
    const gchar *text2 = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(usernameInput));

    g_print("Username : %s\n",text2);
    g_print("Password : %s\n",text1);
}


void connectUser(){
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *connectButton;

    GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "loginWindow.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "loginWindow"));

    connectButton = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "connectButton"));
    g_signal_connect(connectButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(verifyConnect), gtkBuilder);

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));

    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}
```

When the argument is passed by value it ceases to depend on whatever is stored in its former location.

…aaaand BTW, are you really sure you need to free `gtkBuilder` inside `connectUser()`? You are using it in `verifyConnect()` as well, so you probably have to free it at the end of `verifyConnect()`, not at the end of `connectUser()`.